# How can I define local dependencies between roles in a collection in ansible?

Tags: collections, ansible, dependencies, local, roles

I have a question about dependencies between roles in a collection.
In general, I am concerned if it is possible to define dependencies between roles in a collection - local dependencies like a relative path.

I would like to implement scenarios:

1. roleB depends on roleA
2. default scenario of roleC should use roleA in prepare.yml to set up the environment
   or
   default scenario of roleC should use roleA in converge.yml

I would like to get these dependencies as local dependencies.
For case 2, I tried to use the requriments.yml file
with the appropriate entry in molecule.yml

```
---
dependency:
  name: galaxy
driver:
  name: docker
platforms:
 .. ...
provisioner:
  name: ansible
#  env:
#    ANSIBLE_ROLES_PATH: "../../roles"
  playbooks:
    prepare: prepare.yml
  config_options:
    defaults:
      remote_user: ansible
dependency:
  name: galaxy
  options:
    ignore-certs: True
    ignore-errors: True
    requirements-file: requirements.yml
verifier:
  name: ansible
```

But unfortunately I can't solve the error:

```
ERROR    [1m[0;34mUsing /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file[1m[0m
Starting galaxy role install process
- downloading role from file://../../tool-box
[1m[0;31m [ERROR]: failed to download the file: <urlopen error [Errno 2] No such file or[1m[0m
[1m[0;31mdirectory: '/../tool-box'>[1m[0m
[1m[1;35m[WARNING]: - tool-box was NOT installed successfully.[1m[0m
[1m[0;31mERROR! - you can use --ignore-errors to skip failed roles and finish processing the list.[1m[0m
```

Structure of collection with roles:

```
mynamespace
  |
  |--  mycollection
          |
          | --roles
                 |
                 | -- roleA -- 
                 |            |--molecule
                 |                     |
                 |                     |--default
                 |
                 | -- roleB -- 
                 |            |--molecule
                 |                     |
                 |                     |--default
                 |
                 | -- roleC -- 
                 |            |--molecule
                 |                     |
                 |                     |--default
```

Thank you.

---

Update:
See request issue in ansible/galaxy:

https://github.com/ansible/galaxy/issues/2719

I added this because I don't think there is such functionality.

Comment: Did you found some solution on this one? Basically the same story for me.